# Oracle Db links over separated networks

Tags: oracle, networking, database-connection, database-administration, network-security

We have multiple networks (LAN's) to segregate / restrict communications i.e. certain servers are placed on the same network that every user in the organisation is on while some others eg:- highly secure ones are placed on a different network. I have an Oracle database running on a server hosted on user's network and another Oracle database running on a highly secure network (both databases are on AIX servers). We also have an intermediate network in between the user's network and the highly secure network. Now, I want my Oracle database on user's network to communicate with (retrieve data from) the one on critical network via. the intermediate network i.e. the communication should go via. the intermediate network - Can this be achieved if I use a Dblink ? or are there any alternatives for the databases to communicate adhering to the standard I mentioned above.
Note - Currently, I am not looking at the option of moving the Oracle database on user's network to the intermediate network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do this using [Oracle Connection Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28316/cman.htm#NETAG011).  I've seen it used in similar situations but I don't have enough experience with it to say for sure.

Here's the manual's explanation:

> Oracle Connection Manager is a proxy server, an intermediate server
>   that forwards connection requests to database servers or to other
>   proxy servers. It has two primary functions:
>
> - Session multiplexing
> - Access control
>
> ...
>
> With access control, you can use rule-based configuration to filter
>   out certain client requests and accept others.

After you setup and configure OCM then you can create a database link.  In that database link you specify the host database and also add something like `ADDRESS=...(HOST=cman-pc)` for the OCM server.

Comment: Thank you Jon.I will figure out if OCM can work as a solution and I will let you know if it worked or otherwise.

Comment: Hi Jon, a quick update from me - I tried your suggestion to use OCM and did a PoC and it works like a charm - I now have to do some more detailed testing with firewalls etc. but I am sure that would work - Thanks a lot for giving me the idea about using Oracle Connection Manager.